# Could not find `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2`

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I have added a *sqlite-net-pcl* NuGet package to the Xamarin.iOS project. The app ends with the following exception:

> Could not find `SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2`referenced by assembly
>   `SQLite-net, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

Is known any workaround for this issue?

macOS Sierra version: 10.12.5

Xcode version: 8.3.2

sqlite-net-pcl version: 1.0.11

Visual Studio for Mac version: 7.0

Xamarin.iOS version: 10.10.0.33

Answer (score 5):

Fixed in *sqlite-net-pcl* 1.3.1.

Comment: It does. Just update the package to the latest version.

Comment: oh sorry deleting my review, Thanks!