# Impossible to use Sqlite and entityFramework (FileNotFoundException / SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, exception

I'm trying to use a SQlite database in a WPF project, but an error occur. 
I had followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=visual-studio) and everything work fine until I execute my application.

I have two projects (lot of more, but not link to the problem), one where my models and contexts are defined and one where my app is developed and where I want to manage (add delete update) my data.

So the only thing that change is the chapter "Create, read, update & delete", it's set in another project and when the code executes a "db.Add" the following exception is shown :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or 
>   assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

and the stack trace :

> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

I search but not found any solution that works for me. Have you any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: simple google shows that this is a dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137220/could-not-find-sqlitepclraw-batteries-v2

Comment: This doesn't resolve my issue, I install sqlite-net-pcl 1.6.292 in both project and the same error occure

Comment: voted to re-open... not everyone is googling first before posting question to SO, IMHO the goal of community to keep the field as clear as possible... hope someone will handle this

Comment: I totally understand your purpose, but maybe you can let it open for 1 hour. The author can try your solution and answer it. And in my case, the link shows a problem with a Xamarin project, mine is in WPF so it's not exactly the same problem.

Comment: I dont think xamarian and wpf make sense here...

Comment: I don't really know, but how it works is different so we can not pretend that it's the same thing with certainty :). But thanks to try to help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid :O ! 
I just needed to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` in both project and not only in the one with the context....